# How to Calculating the JavaScript Hash for AMP in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, hash, amp-html

At [Calculating the script hash](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/#calculating-the-script-hash) we can see how to calculate the JavaScript hash in case of AMP:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha384');

function generateCSPHash(script) {
  const data = hash.update(script, 'utf-8');
  return (
    'sha384-' +
    data
      .digest('base64')
      .replace(/=/g, '')
      .replace(/\+/g, '-')
      .replace(/\//g, '_')
  );
}
```

How can I do the same in PHP? The following seems not work:

```
<?php
$hash = base64_encode( hash( 'SHA384', 'Give me my hash!', true ) );
```

Comment: You may find this useful
https://github.com/ampproject/amp-wp/blob/develop/includes/amp-helper-functions.php#L1941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a reference from the [WordPress AMP](https://github.com/ampproject/amp-wp/blob/develop/includes/amp-helper-functions.php#L1941) plugin

```php
/**
 * Function to generate AMP scrip hash.
 *
 * @param string $script the script as a string to generate the hash.
 *
 * @return string hash generated from the script.
 */
function amp_generate_script_hash( $script ) {
    $sha384 = hash( 'sha384', $script, true );
    if ( false === $sha384 ) {
        return null;
    }
    $hash = str_replace(
        [ '+', '/', '=' ],
        [ '-', '_', '.' ],
        base64_encode( $sha384 )
    );
    return 'sha384-' . $hash;
}
```

Comment: This dose not work for me the has generated through this is different than the hash showed in the console.

Comment: @UssaidIqbal maybe try trim() to remove whitespaces from script

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function amp_generate_script_hash( $script ) {
    $script = preg_replace('/\s+/g', '', $script); // Remove blank spaces

    $sha384 = hash( 'sha384', $script, true );
    if ( false === $sha384 ) {
        return null;
    }
    $hash = str_replace(
        [ '+', '/', '=' ],
        [ '-', '_', '.' ],
        base64_encode( $sha384 )
    );
    return 'sha384-' . $hash;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).